# Where do Wolverine's claws go?

Tags: marvel, wolverine

What I would like someone to explain is where do those (3 of them) foot long claws go when they retract ???

Comment: +1 for a good question. Before asking, users are encouraged to use the search tool to try to find the answer they're looking for. [Duplicates can be a good thing](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/7943/is-it-encouraged-to-delete-your-own-questions-if-they-have-possible-duplicates), and I know finding the question before asking can be hard if it's worded different, so don't sweat it. Maybe next time search around a bit before asking, but otherwise, thanks for participating and welcome to the site! More info: [tour] and [help]

Comment: Into the bad guys! Oh, when they *retract*.

Answer (score 1):

Here are some pictures to answer you question... 
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: This answer would be better if you stated where you got the images from. :)

Comment: A google search, like the questioner should have done, but they are from the movies and the comics.

Comment: you probably need to be more specific than "google search" and "movies and comics" when citing your sources on SF&F.SE :)